# Cannot resolve R in Android Studio, but app compiles just fine

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1. This error, where the R class is highlighted in red, says Cannot Resolve R, but the app builds and runs just fine, there are no errors in compilation, it just shows R as unresolved reference in the IDE.

This problem only happens in one project that uses Kotlin, and all the other projects open and work without any problems.

I went through most solutions in stackoverflow and that didn't solve the problem.

I'm using ubuntu and it works on other windows pc. Could there be a problem in ubuntu.

These are the solutions that I have tried

1. clean project
2. rebuild project
3. make project
4. invalidate cache and restart
5. sync project with gradle files
6. updating sdk files
7. updating dependency
8. recloning the project
9. checked all my xml files
10. Kotlin plugin was updated

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4aTN.png)

[xml snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIhWd.png)

The issue still persists. Please let me know if any other details are required. 
Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago. I could only solve it by reinstalling android studio

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and it works on other windows pc. Could there be a problem in ubuntu.

Comment: I am not sure. I was using a windows pc so i colved by reinstalling but first you can try making a new project

Comment: Other projects are working only a specific project I'm working on is the problem.

Comment: could you please add snapshot of where you are getting problem

Comment: Did you try InvalidatingCache and Restart for Andoid Studio?

Comment: I have attached the snapshot in the description.

Comment: Yes, I have tried InvalidatingCache and Restart.

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: Thanks guys for the support. I finally got rid of the error by uninstalling and then reinstalling android studio , suggested by @TalhaIsrar

Comment: No problem and good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try reinstalling it

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

this problem with the android studio itself try to clear cache and restart from file --> invalidate the cache and restart if still not working reinstall the android studio and open the project from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio Project and then close Android Studio(Not close Anroid Studio directly), Delete .idea .gradle folder of this project, and reload the project after reopen Android Studio